# How to redraw a CAShapeLayer when modifying his path?

Tags: ios, redraw, cashapelayer

I'm trying to add a subpath to my `CAShapeLayer`'s path, but the changes doesn't show unless I first assing `nil` to the path and then I reassign `myPath` to the `CAShapeLayer`. I've tried with `setNeedsRedisplay` but it doesn't works.

This is the code in the `LoadView` where `myPath` and `shapeLayer` are properties:

```
// The CGMutablePathRef
CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, nil, self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, self.view.center.x + 100.0, self.view.center.y - 100.0);

// The CAShapeLayer
shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = myPath;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

And this is, for example, where I perform the changes to the path. I simply add a new subpath to `myPath`:

```
- (void)handleOneFingerSingleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    // I add a new subpath to 'myPath'
    CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, nil, self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, self.view.center.x + 100.0, self.view.center.y + 100.0);

    // I must do this to show the changes
    shapeLayer.path = nil; 
    shapeLayer.path = myPath;
}
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this?. I'm using iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call  `[shapeLayer didChangeValueForKey:@"path"]` to get the layer to re-render itself.

Answer (score -1):

You should reset path overtime you refresh the path drawing via removeAllPoints before you modify the path.

In Objective C:

```
[path removeAllPoints];
[path moveToPoint:p];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];

shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
```

In Swift 4:

```
path.removeAllPoints()
path.move(to: p1)
path.addLine(to: p2)

shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
```